# Is there a term in MLB sounds like "down lacked command"?

Tags: baseball

At about 1′47″ into the video linked below, it sounds like that the announcer says "Something to watch tonight is velocity, way **down lacked command in his last start** and he's a free agent at the end of the year." There are 3 parts in there, the part before "way down", the part after "and" and the part in between.

I understand "way" usually means "very much", so what does "down lacked command" mean? Does "his last start" refer to the first inning of his last game?

The link begins at 1′42″.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're parsing the English incorrectly. It should be more like:

> Something to watch tonight is velocity: way down, lacked command in his last start

i.e.

- The velocity of his pitches was significantly lower in his last start than typically.
- He had little control (ability to pitch strikes rather than balls) in his last start.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, does "his last start" refer to the first inning of his last game?

Comment: Add that into the question and I'll add it into the answer :-)

Comment: Updated, thank you so much!

Comment: "Last start" just refers to the last game he started, without any particular reference to the inning or innings in that game.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. Does "started a game" mean the pitcher threw the first pitch of that game?

Comment: Correct. Even he is removed immediately after that pitch, he is still the starter, and any other pitches are coming into the game in relief. There aren't many (if any) rules that distinguish between a starter and a relief pitcher, though; the distinction is mostly relevant in determining how various statistics are calculated. For example, a starter can only earn a win if he pitches at least 5 innings.